# dotnet nuget push - The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Tags: .net, gitlab, nuget, push, artifactory

I am building a packge *.nupkg and trying to push it to artifactory using command

dotnet nuget push "/bin/Release/test.1.0.0.nupkg" --source Artifactory --api-key username:password

Getting below exception:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
PUT https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/nuget-dev-local/
error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
error:   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

I would like to know if we can skip SSL verification part in the dotnet push command.